# Unable to get length of the non-string value in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just have started coding in google script and stuck on this step of checking the cell is blank or not .length is working fine with string but not with non-string characters.

[My google script Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euJ0G.png)

[My google sheet snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUwdv.png)

Also some people suggested to use LEN function but I can't find any method "LEN" in google script. Please suggest I'm unable to get clear answer on internet.

Edit:

my exact code is here for better reference

```
const sheetName = "Sheet1";
const sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
//var activeCellAddress = activeCell.getA1Notation();

function create_challan() {
check_range1=sheet.getRange(1,6).getDisplayValues()
check_range2=sheet.getRange(9,6).getDisplayValues()

if (check_range1.length == 0 && check_range2.length == 0) {
    console.log(`Cell A6 is empty.`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Cell A6 is not empty.`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Should `getRange` be used on a single cell?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

When `getValues` is used, when the cell value is a number value, a date object, and a boolean value, the number, date object, and boolean (`Object[][]`) are returned, respectively. By this, when `length` is used, `undefined` is returned. I thought that this situation might be the reason for your current issue of `but not with non-string characters.`.

In order to use `length`, in this case, how about using `getDisplayValues` instead of `getValues`? By this, all values are retrieved as the string value (`String[][]`). By this, `length` can be used for checking whether the cell value is empty. When this is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getDisplayValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0].length == 0) { // or values[i][0] == ""
      console.log(`Cell A${i + 2} is empty.`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Cell A${i + 2} is not empty.`);
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is used for your provided sample image when the cells are "A2" and "A6", `Cell ## is not empty.` is shown in the log. And, other cells show `Cell ## is empty.`.

#### Note:

- Above sample script uses multiple cells. When you want to check only one cell, `getValue` and `getDisplayValue` can be also used for one cell of the same situation. But, in this case, `isBlank` of Class Rnage might be useful. When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

  ```js
  function myFunction() {
    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (sheet.getRange("A2").isBlank()) {
      console.log(`Cell A2 is empty.`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Cell A2 is not empty.`);
    }
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)